# Cytoscape.js warning: "The style value of `label` is deprecated for `width`" when trying to have a node with same width of label

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, cytoscape.js

I'm using [*Cytoscape.js*](https://js.cytoscape.org/) to render a [*dagre layout*](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre) graph.

When styling the *node*, I use the property `width: label` as you can see in the following code:

```
const cy = cytoscape({

  container: document.getElementById('cyGraph'),
  maxZoom: 3,
  minZoom: 0.3,
  elements: dataForCytoscape,

  style: [
    {
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
        'shape': 'round-rectangle',
        'background-color': '#fff',
        'label': 'data(name)',
        'text-valign': 'center',
        'color': '#333333',
        'border-width': 1,
        'border-color': '#2E1A61',
        'width': 'label',
        'font-size': '10px',
        "padding-left": '5px',
        "padding-right": '5px',
        "padding-top": '5px',
        "padding-bottom": '5px'
      }
    },
    {
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
        ...
      }
    }
  ],

  layout: {
    name: 'dagre'
  }

});
```

Code is working and *nodes* get the same width of the inner *labels*, but I get the following **warning** in console:

```
The style value of `label` is deprecated for `width`
```

**Question:** Is there another way to let *Cytoscape* *nodes* to have a width that is the same of the inner *label*?

Comment: what happens if you delete `'width': 'label',`

Comment: The node width collapses and the inner label width exceeds the node's one.

Comment: `'width': 'label'` this is not a valid style. That's the problem. You can set a dynamic width using data properties. for example `'width': 'data(label_width)'` Here every node should have a data property called `label_width`

Comment: `'width': 'label'` this is not a valid style. That's the problem. You can set a dynamic width using data properties. for example `'width': 'data(label_width)'` Here every node should have a data property called `label_width`

Comment: Thank you @canbax for your suggestion. The solution you are proposing is good, but I followed another strategy: to calculate the width, I take the length of the label - from data(name) - and I multiply it for a certain constant (I tried 10, but 7 looks quite good in my case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some tests, I found a solution by myself: I decided to calculate the `width` starting from the `data(name)` field.

So, I changed `'width': 'label'` with the following [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
'width': (node:any) => { return node.data('name').length * 7 }
```

As you can see, I'm taking the `length` of the string of the label (that will contain `name` field) and I am multiplying it for a constant (I started from `10` but then I realized that `7` is the best *in my case*).

This way, I don't have any warning and the graph nodes *fit* the label (`name`) width.

Another solution is the one suggested by [canbax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3209523/canbax) in the comments to my question:

> You can set a dynamic width using data properties. For example
> 'width': 'data(label_width)' Here every node should have a data
> property called label_width

Comment: what about 'height', if I set 'text-max-width' to something about 120?

Answer (score 3):

I remembered another approach. Here you can dynamically generate a canvas element and set font and then measure the text.

```
'width': (node) => { 
    const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext("2d");
    const fStyle = node.pstyle('font-style').strValue;
    const size = node.pstyle('font-size').pfValue + 'px';
    const family = node.pstyle('font-family').strValue;
    const weight = node.pstyle('font-weight').strValue;

    ctx.font = fStyle + ' ' + weight + ' ' + size + ' ' + family;
    return ctx.measureText(node.data('name'));
}
```

This approach might be more costly but it might give you more exact measurements

Comment: It's working for a one line node label. I am struggling in handling multiple lines.
I tried to use `ctx.measureText(node._private.rscratch.labelWrapCachedLines[idx]).width` to measure each line of the label, but the node width does not update until I manually click the node. Do you have any ideas on this? I wonder why 'width':'label' is deprecated in newer CytoscapeJS without an easy fallback for such useful sizing features.